# Official Filebeat docker running on windows not allowing application to rotate the log

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, filebeat

I am using filebeat image - docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:5.4.1 to setup filebeat container locally on windows to read logs from an application and send data to logstash. The application which generate logs will rotate it after '1MB' size.

- I have set close_inactive = 2M. So that filebeat release the handle after 2 minutes.
- When application stops writing data and all the data is read from the file, file handle is released. This is as expected.

My concern is,
- While filebeat container is reading the file, application is not able to rotate the log file after 1MB size.

If i run filebeat as a service (Not inside docker) it works as expected i.e logs are rotated after 1MB.

How can I avoid this ?

Edit: Just for info if it helps, I don't see this issue in linux. Docker filebeat container allow application to rotate the file.

Comment: Here is the link for the discussion on this question in elastic forum - https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filebeat-docker-running-on-windows-not-allowing-application-to-rotate-the-log/89616/9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come to this answer based on the discussion I had with elastic team member at - https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filebeat-docker-running-on-windows-not-allowing-application-to-rotate-the-log/89616/11

This is the response - " VBoxHeadless.exe has the log file open with RW-, I'd say that the shared filesystem used by VirtualBox is to blame. It is not opening the file with FILE_SHARE_DELETE so other applications cannot delete or rename the file."

So its the VirtualBox which is holding the filehandler for the file and not filebeat which is holding the handle.

One suggestion I got is to try Hyper-V driver instead of VirtualBox driver while creating the docker VM on windows.

As i mentioned in my query, it won't happen on linux docker as there is no VM there.